# History of multiple instances of QFileDialog

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

I am using `QT` in my `C++` application. I know that when I use `QFileDialog`, the history is saved in the registry. Suppose I have multiple instances of `QFileDialog` within the application. Can I save the history for each instance separately? As far as I checked, it seems that same registry entry is updated for each instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use different QSettings entry for each QFileDialog instance, with that you manage your history lenght and location.

something like that

```
void callFileDialog(QLinkedList<QString> & fileDialogHistory)
{
    QString fileName =  QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(Q_NULLPTR, "Open File", 
    QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation));
    if(!fileName.isNull()){
        fileDialogHistory << fileName;
    }
}

void saveFileDialogHistory(QLinkedList<QString> & fileDialogHistory, QString 
fileDialogHistoryName = "History_Default")
{
    QSettings settings;
    settings.beginWriteArray(fileDialogHistoryName);
    int index = 0;
    for (QLinkedList<QString>::iterator it = fileDialogHistory.begin(); it != fileDialogHistory.end(); ++it){
        settings.setArrayIndex(index);
        settings.setValue("filePath", QFileInfo(*it).filePath());
        index++;
    }
    settings.endArray();
}
```

Comment: Can you please help with a small example

Comment: You could follow the Qt documention with their basic usage http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#basic-usage

Comment: After the basic usage you could use section foreach QFileDialog for example http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#section-and-key-syntax

Comment: And for the array serialization you could use beginReadArray and beginWritteArray http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#beginReadArray